# Where can I download the Eclipse 3.5.2 Delta Pack?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, delta-pack

Where can I download the Eclipse 3.5.2 Delta Pack?

It's no longer available via the download pages on eclipse.org :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit this page:
[Delta Pack](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.2-201002111343/solPlatform.php#DeltaPack)
It should take you straight to the delta pack link.

Comment: I've been searching for this for an hour! Thank you!

Comment: Nice ... it's been moved to archive.eclipse.org; the estimated download time is >2h ... *sigh* ;-)